# Unity: export to gltf 2.0 format

Tags: unity-game-engine, gltf

Is there a way to get a Unity store asset downloaded (consisting of a folder containing FBX model + separate animations in FBX + separate textures in png etc) as a gltf binary?

If so, can someone guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Unity glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF)?

Comment: No. Is that a library? I am not a 3D developer but am building a webVR site and need to use some FBX model with separate FBX animations from the asset store. Thanks @emackey. Let me investigate this direction. I was hoping to find a direct export to GLTF but did not notice it in Unity. My challenge is to add the animations. There are third party tools that export FBX to GLTF and they work; but none of them give an option of specifying separate animation FBX files.

Comment: I wrote a blog post (https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/11/06/creating-animated-gltf-characters-with-mixamo-and-blender/) that describes joining FBX files with separate FBX animations in Blender, and exporting to glTF. To export glTF directly from Unity, that UnityGLTF library is the best (and possibly only) option. This question may turn out to be too open-ended for Stack Overflow, so I'd suggest asking in the glTF Gitter if you need more help: https://gitter.im/KhronosGroup/glTF

Comment: Thanks Don McCurdy. For some reasons the FBX files downloaded from Unity asset store are in ASCII and Blender throws an error expecting them to be in Binary. I checked the net but could not find a way to convert the ASCII to Binary. Will check out in the link you have suggeted. Many thanks. R

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the party, but hopefully it can help someone else in the future.

You can export from Unity to glTF easily using the [Plattar glTF Exporter](https://github.com/Plattar/gltf-exporter).
It does not seem to be possible to export in glB (the binary form), only glTF, though there are [tools to convert from glTF to glB](https://github.com/TimvanScherpenzeel/gltf-to-glb), some of them [available online](https://glb-packer.glitch.me/).

You can also convert an FBX from ASCII to binary format easily, from within Unity, using the [Unity FBX Exporter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@2.0/manual/exporting.html) package, available from the Package Manager.

Comment: Does this Plarrar gltf export support runtime export?

Comment: I only used it as an Editor tool, but apparently [not by default](https://github.com/Plattar/gltf-exporter/issues/12), although it may be possible by modifying the source (although perhaps [other tools](https://github.com/vrm-c/UniVRM) can do it right off the bat).

Answer (score 0):

I am even later to the party with Blender 2.82, but also for future reference:

- import base fbx model
- rename animation in inspector to base
- import walk fbx model
- rename animation in inspector to walk
- go to animation tab, select dope sheet, then action editor
- select base animation and 'push down'
- select walk animation and 'push down'
- delete walk model and mesh
- export to gltf/glb
- check in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

This was tested with Malbers fox model.
I can provide a video if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UniVRM](https://github.com/vrm-c/UniVRM). It supports editor time export as well as runtime export. It supports the VRM format, as well as gltf. This is the only asset that supports runtime export out of the box, to my knowledge.